# Working with Sales Object and Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am working on a form to add people to a contact object in Salesforce and update a data extension. I am checking to see if the email address exists in the Contacts object and update or inserting accordingly. However, after stripping everything back down, I am noticing that i can only choose to insert a contact into salesforce OR insert a row into the data extension after the ELSE command but not both. Any clues as to why?

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

/* check if lead already exists */

  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Contact",
   "Id,Email",
   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
   )

  /* get id if lead exists */

  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @LeadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")

    /* update existing lead */
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Contact", v(@LeadId),
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "SFMC_Load_Criteria_Met__c", 'True'
     )


  ELSE

   /* create a new lead */
  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Contact", 1,
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )

set @email = RequestParameter("email") 

set @result = InsertData("pref_newsletters", "Email", @email)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't able to do both (update salesforce & Insert data) because the insert data is in the "Else" part. Your code evaluated in "If" part and exit.

But please note for update if the record already exists then it better to use [upsert data](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/) function, since you are doing both insert and update. If you try insert data then it will throw an error.

I have modified your code there has been some syntax error. Below is the updated one.

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

/* check if lead already exists */

SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
"Contact",
"Id,Email",
"Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
)

/* get id if lead exists */

IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
SET @LeadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")

/* update existing lead */
SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
  "Contact", @LeadId,
  "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
  "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
  "SFMC_Load_Criteria_Met__c", 'True'
 )
 set @email = RequestParameter("email") 
set @result = InsertData("pref_newsletters", "Email", @email)

ELSE

/* create a new lead */
SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
    "Contact", 1,
    "Email", RequestParameter("email")
   )

set @email = RequestParameter("email") 

set @result = InsertData("pref_newsletters", "Email", @email)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you, the UpsertDE function was the trick.

Comment: okay great!  @EricN